# Compare an attribute for two possible values during PutItem expression on dynamoDB

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to avoid creating items on dynamoDB that have the same `hashkey` and two possible values of `rangekey`.

- `haskey` is a unique identifier.
- `rangeKey` can have two possible values:

  ```
  'bose~quitecomfort'
  'bose~nicecomfort'
  ```

I'm trying to achieve something like:

```
ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(hashkey) AND attribute_does_not_begin_with(bose~)
```

The below expressions didn't work:

```
ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(hashkey) AND (rangeKey <> :quitecomfort OR rangeKey <> :nicecomfort)',

ExpressionAttributeValues: 
{
  ':quitecomfort' : { S: bose~quitecomfort},
  ':nicecomfort' : { S: bose~nicecomfort}
}
```

Comment: "avoid creating items on dynamoDB that have the same hashkey": same as what, another item? Conditions only work within a single item, and DynamoDB doesn't have constraints beyond uniqueness of the primary key. Could you please post some sample data and desired output of the command you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you're trying to achieve cannot happen in a single request. When DynamoDB does a condition check it can only do so for a single item, i.e the item which you are currently inserting/updating.

If you want to do conditions on other items then you need to use `TransactWriteItem` API where you can specify conditional checks on items which are not part of the modification. However, you must still provide the full key of the items.

##### TRANSACTION

1. PUT item pk=uuid AND sk=bose~quitecomfort CONDITION not_exists(PK)
2. CHECK item PK=uuid AND sk=bose~nicecomfort CONDITION not_exists(PK)